# Uncaught Error: [vuex] getters should be function but "getters.products" in module "prods" is []

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've reduced this code to the bare minimal, but I'm still not sure where this problem is coming from, but this is the first sentence of the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [vuex] getters should be function but "getters.products" in module "prods" is []
```

This is my main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from './router.js';
import storage from './store.js';
import App from './App.vue';
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(storage);
app.mount('#app');
```

This is my router.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import ProductsList from './ProductsList.vue';
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    { path: '/', redirect: '/products' },
    { path: '/products', component: ProductsList },
  ]
});
export default router;
```

This is my store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
// import productsModule from './products.js';
const products = createStore({
  namespaced: true,
  state() {
    return {
      allProducts: [
        {
          id: 'p1',
          image: "",
          title: 'Books',
          description: 'Books collection.',
          price: 20
        },
      ]
    };
  },
  getters: {
    products(state) {
      return state.allProducts;
    }
  }
})
const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    prods: products,
  },
});
export default store;
```

This is my App.vue minus the style:

```
<template>
  <the-header></the-header>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
<script>
import TheHeader from './TheHeader.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    TheHeader
  },
}
</script>
```

This is my ProductsList.vue minus the style:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <product-item
        v-for="prod in products"
        :key="prod.id"
        :id="prod.id"
        :title="prod.title"
        :image="prod.image"
        :description="prod.description"
        :price="prod.price"
      ></product-item>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import ProductItem from './ProductItem.vue';
export default {
  // inject: ['products'],
  components: {
    ProductItem,
  },
  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.getters['prods/products'];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And this is my ProductItem.vue minus the style:

```
<template>
  <li class="product">
    <div class="product__data">
      <div class="product__image">
        <img :src="image" :alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="product__text">
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        <h4>${{ price }}</h4>
        <p>{{ description }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product__actions">
      <button>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['id', 'image', 'title', 'price', 'description'],
};
</script>
```

My code including the styles and the workable products.js can be found at:

https://github.com/maxloosmu/vue-complete/tree/main/15/vuex-0012/src

Could someone help point me to why this way of using Vuex getters is wrong?  Or is it due to another problem with Vuex?

Comment: Module != store. There should be only one `createStore` call

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered an answer to my question.  In my store.js, I do not use createStore twice, but just once.  That will resolve the problem:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
const products = {
  namespaced: true,
  state() {
    return {
      allProducts: [
        {
          id: 'p1',
          image: "",
          title: 'Books',
          description: 'Books collection.',
          price: 20
        },
      ]
    };
  },
  getters: {
    products(state) {
      return state.allProducts;
    }
  }
}
const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    prods: products,
  },
});
export default store;
```